# TeXstudio: How to switch the master document that is compiled and displayed

Tags: texstudio, modules

I will write a very long report and I would like to modularize the process.

What I would like to achieve is to keep every chapter and section in different documents, and compile them individually.
This way, I will release the burden of compiling a huge document after a few lines of change.

Here is my setup:

```
%%%maindoc.tex%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{docmute,import}
\begin{document}
\subimport{./}{intro}
\subimport{./}{conclusion}
\end{document}

%%%intro.tex%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{docmute,import}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} \label{chap:intro}
This is an introduction.
\subimport{./}{motivation}
\subimport{./}{results}
\end{document}

%%%motivation.tex%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\section{Motivation} \label{sec:motivation}
Very much motivation, great success.
\end{document}

%%%results.tex%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\section{Results} \label{sec:results}
Our results are very interesting but also are top secret.
\end{document}

%%%conclusion.tex%%%

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Conclusion} \label{chap:conclusion}
To conclude, this is not a great report.
\end{document}
```

Whenever I try to compile any of the .tex files given above, it compiles and shows the `maindoc.tex`.
How can I make an adjustment such that when I compile `motivation.tex`, the main file would not compile with it?

Comment: I don't think that what you describe actually happens. It is probably an artefact of your TeX-IDE that you use to edit files and viewing the result. You probably have to tell your IDE that the new file that you are working on is `motivation.tex`, then it will also show `motivation.pdf` and not `maindoc.pdf`. LaTeX has no possibility to access `conclusion.tex` or `results.tex` when processing `motivation.tex`. It simply doesn't know about these files.

Comment: Side note: It may be that you will experience problems with `docmute`. First, it executes hooks associated with `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` (introduced in LaTeX at the beginning of October 2020) multiple times; at the moment I'm just aware of CJK packages where this is a problem, but more packages will follow. Moreover, if you distribute files over various directories, `subimport` doesn't handle some adjustments in the preamble correctly (or you have to duplicate the preamble). You may want to consider the `subfiles` package as an alternative of `docmute`+`import`.

Comment: Anyway, I ran LaTeX on your sample files, and everything worked (TeXlive 2020).

Comment: @gernot I'm using TeXstudio and I cannot compile and see the files individually for some reason. Even if I use `subfile` instead of `import`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the discussion in the comments, the problem turned out to be related to TeXstudio. The question is actually **how to tell TeXstudio which of the tex files is the root document that it should compile and display in the viewer.**

**Method1: Structure pane** To the left, TeXstudio displays the structure of the document in a window labeled `Structure`. (If there is no such window, click on the tiny button in the left bottom corner.) In the structure pane, right-click on the TeX-file that is supposed to become the new root file, and select the item `Set as explicit root document`.

**Method2: Options menu** Open the file that is to become the root document in the editor window. In the top bar, click `Options`, move the cursor in the drop-down menu over the item `Root document` and select in the side menu `Set Current Document As Explicit Root`.